# Serve a styled WFS via QGIS server

Tags: wfs, style

I recieved a huge data-dump with several hundrets of layers. I need to style those layers and make the data including the style available to different GIS-Softwares (MapInfo, QGIS, ESRI). I thought, the most simple way to be independend from the end user's software would be to provide the data via WFS. Is it possible to serve a style with the WFS?

So far i found out, that if i include

> sld=URL-to-SLD-file

at the end of the wfs url, it should work  - i did not suceed so far unfortunately.

Example:

```
http://<server_address>/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&typename=my_layer&sld=http://<path_to_sld_file>
```

WMS is not really an option, as feature querying is a must!
I'm using QGIS server so far (3.28)

Comment: You can query with a WMS using a GetFeatureInfo request.

Answer (score 1):

WFS is for serving raw data there is no way to style it on the server. If you want to style it you will need to serve it as WMS, possibly with a side of WFS for advanced users who want to do analysis or produce their own maps.